# i don't know what to do next in this arduino example

Tags: arduino

I'm a beginner and I dont know what to do next:

In the line that said:

```
set the cursor to column 0, line 1
```

I do not what to do with this line

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.print("hello, world!");
}

void loop() {
  // set the cursor to column 0, line 1
  // (note: line 1 is the second row, since counting begins with 0):
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  // print the number of seconds since reset:
  lcd.print(millis() / 1000);
}
```

Comment: That one is a comment explaining the lines below. It is saying you that the instruction `lcd.setCursor(0, 1);` means "set the cursor to column 0, line 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax:lcd.setCursor(col, row) 
lcd.setCursor(0,1);
that means you are setting your cursor to 0th column and 1st row
Your text will be displayed at 0 th column and 1 st row in LCD.